# Has anyone used OpenCalais succesfully in a project?

Tags: organization

In [a previous question here on programmers](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/35904/pointers-to-implementing-a-taxonomy-system), the [OpenCalais](http://www.opencalais.com) system has been referenced as a solution.

Has anyone used [OpenCalais](http://www.opencalais.com)? Can you identify pros and cons of the system ?

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used it, but when I signed up for it using a unique email address I haven't used anywhere else, I was spammed relentlessly.  Apparently they've either been compromised and didn't bother telling people or they sold their database to spammers.  If you use it, make sure you use a disposable email address.